# Sharepoint 2007 json is undefined error with IE8

Tags: sharepoint

Hi all
some users with IE8reported a javascript error that displays

> json is undefined

whenever they browse any page in our sharepoint portal.

other users with IE8 did not report that erro and said that everything is OK.

did anyone encounter such an error before ?

thanks

Comment: can you provide more infomation, what page are you viewing, what is on the page, are you using any custom components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks djeeg.
the thing I found that those users had some plugins like Divx installed to their browsers.
when they removed the plugins everything worked fine.